# Django autocomplete does not work

Tags: autocomplete, django-admin, django-autocomplete-light

I'm using django-autocomplete-light 3.2.1 in django 1.10.2. In admin instead of autocomplete field I see a select field. I followed the instructions from [here](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/).

package urls.py

```
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^autocomplete/', include('apps.vehicle.urls')),)
```

Inside apps folder I have a vehicle app. Inside I have following codes.
1) views.py:

```
  from dal import autocomplete
  from .models import Model

  class ModelAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
      def get_queryset(self):
    # Don't forget to filter out results depending on the visitor !
          if not self.request.user.is_authenticated():
               return Model.objects.none()

    qs = Model.objects.all()

    if self.q:
        qs = qs.filter(name__istartswith=self.q)

    return qs
```

2) forms.py:

```
from django import forms

from dal import autocomplete
from .models import Model, ChassisCode

class ChassisCodeForm(forms.ModelForm):
   test_field = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Model.objects.all(),
        widget=autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='model-autocomplete')
    )

class Meta:
    model = ChassisCode
    fields = ('__all__')
```

3) admin.py:

```
class ChassisCodeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ChassisCodeForm

admin.site.register(ChassisCode, ChassisCodeAdmin)
```

4) finally urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from .views import ModelAutocomplete

urlpatterns = [
    url(
        r'^model-autocomplete/$',
        ModelAutocomplete.as_view(),
        name='model-autocomplete',
    ),
]
```

But, autocomplete does not work. In admin I see only common admin select field. What may be wrong in my codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I checked Firefox console and found few errors which mean that either there are some code errors or static files are not loaded. After that I checked static folder in my server and discovered that autocomplete folder was not there. Then, just run the following code to solve the issue.

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Answer (score 0):

Making the

```
list_display = ('balabala','balabala',)
```

before the *form* in your *ModelAdmin*, this works for me.